# Java statistics package for Robust Statistics

Tags: java, statistics

I'm looking for a java package for "Robust Statistics". Please Note the meaning of ["Robust"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics) here.

I know about Apache commons Math  [Descriptive statistics](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/index.html) and Summary Statistics but they only provide non-robust statistics.

An example here would be [median absolute deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation)

Comment: Do you have examples of robust stats besides the MAD? That can be calculated quite easily and hardly needs a package of its own. Beyond that, robust statistics is a very broad and application-dependent topic.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether this will give you an exact solution. But you can derive those features using apache math library. 
This is an example for deriving mean absolute deviation.

```
public double mad(double [] autoCorrelationValues){
    double [] tempTable = new double[autoCorrelationValues.length];
    Median m = new Median();
    double medianValue = m.evaluate(autoCorrelationValues);
    for(int i=0 ; i<autoCorrelationValues.length ;i++){
        tempTable[i] = Math.abs(autoCorrelationValues[i] - medianValue);
    }
    return m.evaluate(tempTable); 
}
```